# Go build is giving permission denied error on mac

Tags: go

I am trying to run `go build` and seeing the following error. `go run` works fine

`open /Users/an../Library/Caches/go-build/32/3284dc1dfe0121246372cec7d0efeba47a547120b3fa696ef6283422d69cd994-a: permission denied`

Comment: What is the permission on this folder? Does it even exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are encountering is likely due to a permissions issue with the Go build cache directory. When you run go build, Go will try to write the compiled object files to the cache directory for faster future builds. However, it seems that Go doesn't have the necessary permissions to write to the cache directory, hence the "permission denied" error.

Ensure that you have the appropriate permissions to write to the cache directory. You can use the ls command to check the permissions and ownership of the cache directory:

```
ls -ld /Users/an../Library/Caches/go-build
```

If you don't have write permissions on this directory, you can change the ownership to your user:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/an../Library/Caches/go-build
```